# delphi bitmap position manipulation

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I've this event to draw on a bitmap :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
  SrcBmp,MyBitmap: TBitmap;
  MyRect: TRectF;
begin
   SrcBmp:=TBitmap.CreateFromFile('android.png');
   try
      MyBitmap := TBitmap.CreateFromFile('fav.png');
       try
     MyRect.Left :=0;
     MyRect.Top := 0;
     MyRect.Bottom := MyBitmap.Height;
     MyRect.Right := MyBitmap.Width;

     SrcBmp.Canvas.BeginScene() ;
     SrcBmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(MyBitmap,MyRect
     ,MyRect, 50);
     SrcBmp.Canvas.EndScene;
      finally
     MyBitmap.Free;
     end;

   Image1.Bitmap.Assign(SrcBmp);

   finally
   SrcBmp.Free;
   end;
end;
```

The Result is : 
[image]

But what i want to get is this result : 
[image]

I tried to decrease the MyRect.Left and MyRect.Top , but that didn't give the 2nd result .

PS: the fav.png dimensions is 16x16 .

Many thanks

Comment: DstRect is where the bitmap is to be drawn. So use an additional rect which specifies where you want to draw and pass it to DrawBitmap.

Comment: @Sertac , thank you , but I still need this 2nd rect coordinates so that I can get the 2nd result . Can you please give me these coordinates ( top , bottom ).

Comment: left=android.png.width - 16, top=android.png.height - 16, width=16, height=16.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SrcBmp,MyBitmap: TBitmap;
  MyRect, 
  DestRect: TRectF;
  begin
  SrcBmp:=TBitmap.CreateFromFile('android.png');
  try
    MyBitmap := TBitmap.CreateFromFile('fav.png');
    try
      MyRect:=TRectF.Create(0,0,MyBitmap.Width, MyBitmap.Height);
      DestRect:=TRectF.Create(ScrBmp.Width-MyBitmap.width, ScrBmp.Height-MyBitmap.Height, MyBitmap.Width, MyBtmap.Height);
      SrcBmp.Canvas.BeginScene() ;
      SrcBmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(MyBitmap,MyRect, DestRect, 50);
      SrcBmp.Canvas.EndScene;
      DestRect.Free;
      MyRect.Free;
    finally
      MyBitmap.Free;
    end;
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign(SrcBmp); 
  finally
    SrcBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```